# React Link not working on same url type dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React.
I am creating simple blog website using React.
I have some problem on My BlogDetail page, I am not able to change dom for realted blogs.
Url is changing but dom is not refreshing. other links are working but not post one.
Here is my Routes:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/blogs/:slug/" component={BlogDetail}/>
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

and here is my BlogDetail export

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchToProps)(BlogDetail));
```

Comment: Check this post. It will provide you with the reason and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803740/link-on-same-component-not-resfresh-page/61803842#61803842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user componentDidMount here to remount your dom with new id/slug

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
        let slug =  this.props.match.params.slug; 
        // Do something with slug
    }
}
```